# How to log "send failed" to a file instead of showing a pop-up message

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, blazeds

I am working with Flex 4.1 on Linux but I suppose this problem must be common to all versions of Flex.

I am working on a Flex client front-end which connects to a Java back-end (in Tomcat) via BlazeDS. All of this works OK 99.9% of the time. However, from time to time (let's say, if the client browser has been open for several hours), the user gets a pop-up message saying "Send failed". It seems to be a harmless transient error -- if the user closes the pop-up, the front-end carries on as usual and seems to continue to work as expected.

Is there a way to have the "send failed" message written to a log file instead of opening a pop-up message?

As a separate issue, if anyone has seen occasional, transient "send failed" errors, I would be interested to hear about that. If you have some solution to make them go away, that would be terrific.

Comment: A separate issue should be a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION 1 : Use simple [trace() feature](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fd6.html)

1. Install the [debugger version of Flash Player](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html)
2. Set `TraceOutputFileEnable` to 1 in your [mm.cfg](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fc9.html) file
3. the log of your application will in "flashlog.txt" file (see [Log file location](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSda78ed3a750d6b8f-4867184d1239f9d0558-8000.html))
4. Use `trace("message")` to log your messages to "flashlog.txt" file.

SOLUTION 2 : [Use logging API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f0f.html):

```
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    creationComplete="initLogging();"
    height="600">

    <s:layout> 
        <s:VerticalLayout/> 
    </s:layout>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.logging.targets.*;
        import mx.logging.*;

        [Bindable]
        public var myData:ArrayCollection;

        private function initLogging():void {
            /* Create a target. */
            var logTarget:TraceTarget = new TraceTarget();

            /* Log only messages for the classes in the mx.rpc.* and 
               mx.messaging packages. */
            logTarget.filters=["mx.rpc.*","mx.messaging.*"];

            /* Log all log levels. */
            logTarget.level = LogEventLevel.ALL;

            /* Add date, time, category, and log level to the output. */
            logTarget.includeDate = true;
            logTarget.includeTime = true;
            logTarget.includeCategory = true;
            logTarget.includeLevel = true;

            /* Begin logging. */
            Log.addTarget(logTarget);
        }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- HTTPService is in the mx.rpc.http.* package -->
        <mx:HTTPService id="srv" 
            url="../assets/trace_example_data.xml" 
            useProxy="false" 
            result="myData=ArrayCollection(srv.lastResult.data.result)"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <mx:LineChart id="chart" dataProvider="{myData}" showDataTips="true">
        <mx:horizontalAxis>
            <mx:CategoryAxis categoryField="month"/>
        </mx:horizontalAxis>
        <mx:series>
            <mx:LineSeries yField="apple" name="Apple"/>
            <mx:LineSeries yField="orange" name="Orange"/>
            <mx:LineSeries yField="banana" name="Banana"/>
        </mx:series>
    </mx:LineChart>

    <s:Button id="b1" click="srv.send();" label="Load Data"/>

</s:Application>
```